# ASP.NET Pass Variable to JSON Deserialized HTTP Response Object

Tags: asp.net, json, http

Is there a good way to dynamically pass a string variable in place of a deserialized object definition?  How I mean, is that the code snippet below is proper syntax to deserialize the JSON response object in order to store the returned data types in a database for further processing.

```
        string inputSymbol = "SNAP";

        var client = new RestClient("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/" + inputSymbol + "/quotes");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ReadAccessToken());
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        dynamic quote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);

        string closePrice = quote.SNAP.closePrice;
        string symbol = quote.SNAP.symbol;
        string openPrice = quote.SNAP.openPrice;
        string highPrice = quote.SNAP.highPrice;
        string lowPrice = quote.SNAP.lowPrice;
        string lastPrice = quote.SNAP.lastPrice;
        string volume = quote.SNAP.totalVolume;
```

This is a shortened sample JSON response for reference -

{
"SNAP": {
"symbol": "SNAP",
"openPrice": 56.39,
"highPrice": 64.44,
"lowPrice": 55.51,
"closePrice": 63.64
}
}

For example, I need to specify - quote.SNAP.closePrice - as in the proper syntax above to access the returned closePrice and store in a database.

What I am trying to accomplish, is something more along the lines of the example below for dynamic processing based on the passed variable and not static:

```
string inputSymbol = "SNAP";
string test = "closePrice";
string closeP = quote + "." + inputSymbol + "." + test;
```

I've tried many different variations through exhaustive testing, but I either get a Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference, String or binary data would be truncated in table, or 'string' does not contain a definition for 'SNAP' when trying to convert the response ToString();  None of these error message searches online are applicable to my use case.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize to `JObject` which has [indexer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJson.htm) to perform such dynamic querying:

```
var response = @"{ 'SNAP': { 'symbol': 'SNAP', 'openPrice': 56.39, 'highPrice': 64.44, 'lowPrice': 55.51, 'closePrice': 63.64 } }";

var quote = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response); // Or JObject.Parse(response)
string inputSymbol = "SNAP";
string test = "closePrice";
string closeP = quote[inputSymbol][test].ToString();
Console.WriteLine(closeP); // prints 63.64
```